# thin server with GoDaddy ssl - access from osx

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, godaddy, thin

I have a thin server that i run with a certificate from GoDaddy and a private key i created before. I also have a file "gd_bundle.crt" that's probably required for access from osx (or iphones).

thin only accepts my certificate and private key but i don't know how to give it "gd_bundle.crt".

What should it do?

Comment: Eugh. GoDaddy.  Haven't you heard about SOPA and why GoDaddy should be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's no option to feed thin a certificate path, then you'll want to create a single-file bundle which includes your certificate and the full path up to the root.

However, I wouldn't advise doing it with the bundle downloaded from GoDaddy - that bundle has an invalid certificate signing path - GoDaddy messed it up (see my answer discussing this [here](https://serverfault.com/a/254804/72586)).

As in the answer that I linked above with this certificate bundle (that they still haven't fixed!), you'll want to basically build your own certificate bundle.  Load up the web site in a browser that figures out the trust path up to the root, and you'll want to export each individual certificate as x509; your own cert (which you already have), any intermediates in order, all the way up to the root.

Then, construct a text file with the pieces from those exports appended together, in reverse order, like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(Your certificate's base64 data here)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(intermediate certificate's base64 data here)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(root certificate's base64 data here)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And one word of warning - do this in a plain text editor; editors like wordpad will replace `--` with `–`, which will cause OpenSSL to fail to load the certificate.